# Problema para hacer login en android studio usando KSOAP

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación móvil en Android Studio consumiendo desde un WebServices hecho en asmx. Solo que al momento de ejecutar mi app y de ingresar el usuario y password me manda un error

> E/Response: Error: Can't create handler inside thread that has not
>   called Looper.prepare()

Dejo aquí mi código que tengo en mi `activity`

```
package com.example.onc_lap.oncontrolmobile;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.SoapFault;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class Principal extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText usuario;
    EditText password;
    private Button ingresar;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String TAG = "Response";
    public final int dialogo_alert = 0;
    public String msje = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        usuario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usuario);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        ingresar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ingresar);
        ingresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String username = usuario.getText().toString();
                String pass = password.getText().toString();
                new webserv().execute();
            } //fin del click view
        });
    }

    class webserv extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        public String NAMESPACE = "http://ONControl_MobileWS/";
        public String METHOD_NAME = "Login";
        public String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ONControl_MobileWS/Login";
        public String SOAP_ADDRESS;
        private SoapObject request;
        private HttpTransportSE transporte;
        private SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
           Login();
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Principal.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Iniciando sesion ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setMax(10);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(boolean result) {
                    if (result){
                        Toast.makeText(Principal.this, "Tarea finalizada!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
        }

        public void Login(){
            SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9020/ONControl_MobileWS.asmx";
            request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            PropertyInfo pi= new PropertyInfo();
            envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            transporte = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);

            request.addProperty("usuario", usuario.getText().toString());
            request.addProperty("password", password.getText().toString());

            try {
                transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                SoapPrimitive resultado_xml =(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                String res = resultado_xml.toString();
                Principal.this.msje=res;
                // mostramos la respuesta en un toast
                Toast.makeText(Principal.this.getBaseContext(), res,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if(res.equals("Gracias por Iniciar Sesion")){
                    Principal.this.usuario.getText().toString();
                    Principal.this.usuario.setText("");
                    Principal.this.password.setText("");
                    //envia al otro activity
                    Intent intent=new Intent("android.intent.menu");
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
     //run
}
```

Comment: Hugo, si usas Asynctask, únicamente puedes realizar cambios a tu interfaz de usuario desde el método  onPostExecute(), revisa mi respuesta.

Comment: Como comentario si defines tu Asynctask  AsyncTask<String, String, String> , debe ser onPostExecute(String result)

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que intentas actualizar o realizar cambios en la UI desde un thread en background, lo cual es únicamente permitido en [`onPostExecute()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)).

Al ejecutarse tu método [`doInBackground()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...)) del `Asynctask` se ejecuta `Login()` el cual trata de realizar operaciones como:

```
 // mostramos la respuesta en un toast
            Toast.makeText(Principal.this.getBaseContext(), res,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if(res.equals("Gracias por Iniciar Sesion")){
                Principal.this.usuario.getText().toString();
                Principal.this.usuario.setText("");
                Principal.this.password.setText("");
                //envia al otro activity
                Intent intent=new Intent("android.intent.menu");
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
```

Trata de mover estas operaciones a  [`onPostExecute()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)) de tu `Asynctask`, que es donde podrías modificar sin problemas tu UI.

> **[onPostExecute()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result))** se ejecutará en el hilo de la interfaz de usuario.

Por lo tanto tu clase tendría que cambiar a :

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class Principal extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static String TAG = "Response";
    EditText usuario;
    EditText password;
    private Button ingresar;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    public final int dialogo_alert = 0;
    public String msje = "";
    private String res = "";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        usuario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usuario);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        ingresar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ingresar);
        ingresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String username = usuario.getText().toString();
                String pass = password.getText().toString();
                new webserv().execute();

            } //fin del click view

        });
    }


    class webserv extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        public String NAMESPACE = "http://ONControl_MobileWS/";
        public String METHOD_NAME = "Login";
        public String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ONControl_MobileWS/Login";
        public String SOAP_ADDRESS;
        private SoapObject request;
        private HttpTransportSE transporte;
        private SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            return Login();
        }


        protected void onPreExecute() {

            Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Principal.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Iniciando sesion ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setMax(10);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            Principal.this.msje = res;
            // mostramos la respuesta en un toast
            Toast.makeText(Principal.this.getBaseContext(), res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (res.equals("Gracias por Iniciar Sesion")) {
                Principal.this.usuario.getText().toString();
                Principal.this.usuario.setText("");
                Principal.this.password.setText("");
                //envia al otro activity
                Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.menu");
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
                Toast.makeText(Principal.this, "Tarea finalizada!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        public String Login() {
            SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9020/ONControl_MobileWS.asmx";
            request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
            envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            transporte = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);

            request.addProperty("usuario", usuario.getText().toString());
            request.addProperty("password", password.getText().toString());

            try {
                transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                SoapPrimitive resultado_xml = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
                return resultado_xml.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                return ""; retorna una cadena vacía en caso de error...
            }

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: entonces en el doInBackground solo pongo mi conexion a mi web services?

Comment: tu conexión y el resultado de tu respuesta, y en onPostExecute()  poddrías mostrar el toast, modificar el texto, etc. Realiza el cambio y funcionaría correctamente.

Comment: mira ya lo tengo asi.. ya lo movi pero me manda un error que dice /Response: Error: null

Comment: te puse mi codigo como lo modifique... pero me manda ese error de null

Comment: Hugo, borra la respuesta que agregaste por favor ya que te podrían dar puntos negativos y no es correcto agregar eso como respuesta, dame unos segundos y en mi respuesta te agrego como modificas tu código. =)

Comment: YA LA BORRE, GRACIAS POR DECIRME ES QUE APENAS ES MI PRIMERA PUBLICACION EN ESTE FORO.. TE AGREDECIA MUCHO QUE ME DIJIERAS COMO.. POR QUE LA VERDAD YA ME ME HICE PELOTAS.....

Comment: He editado la clase, pon atención en lo que realiza en el método onPostExecute(), Supongo que tu método Login() funciona correctamente verdad? jejej, prueba que tal funciona.

Comment: fijate que ya ejecuto mi app ingreso usuario y passoword y en mi emulador  y cuando le doy click en ingresar me manda un mensaje en mi emulador que dice "FALSE" Y DESPUES DE COMO 3 SEGUNDOS ME MANDA MI MENSAJE QUE TENGO EN ESTA PARTE                                     Toast.makeText(Principal.this, "Tarea finalizada!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                                                y en el android monitor me aparece este mensaje                                       W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

Comment: Bueno eso es otro detalle completamente distinto,  "W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented" regularmente es un problema en los emuladores, yo trato de usar dispositivos reales. Sería buena idea que eso lo pongas en una nueva pregunta para compartir con otros usuarios. Has usado el emulador anteriormente???

Comment: yo cree ese emulador... pero ya corri la app en mi disposito movil... y al momento de ingresar el usuario y password... me un error que dice FALSE Y YA NO HACE NADA

Comment: Porque retornar `null` si el AsyncTask esta definido como `<String, String, String>` para algo están no? Es lioso obtener un resultado de manera elegante de la manera en la que está codificada la clase.

Comment: si ya me responde mi webservices use un link donde te genera todos los metodos.. solo que te queria pedir tu ayuda para revisar mi codigo de mi boton para hacer el login... no me funciona

Comment: @RosendoRopher tienes mucha razón Rosendo, opté mantener ese código para no confundirlo. he cambiado un poco el código. +100

Comment: @HugoRodriguez , cambia a :  new webserv().execute("");

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo lo siguiente, opino que está bien ayudar a encontrar fallos en el código; pero también es oportuno corregir errores de [Sintaxis](http://codehero.co/java-desde-cero-sintaxis-basica/) que puede presentar el código, recordar que los lenguajes de programación tienen un conjunto de reglas de escritura que estandarizan los programas para que cualquier desarrollador del mundo pueda comprenderlo.

También es cierto que se deben corregir implementaciones poco óptimas del recurso que es foco del problema planteado, abajo te coloco tu clase modificada con algunas observaciones que te serán útiles, si es que estás empezando en esto del desarrollo. Tener en mente que al tratarse literalmente de un "lenguaje" todos debemos respetar las reglas.

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class Principal extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static String TAG = "Response";
    EditText usuario;
    EditText password;
    private Button ingresar;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    public final int dialogo_alert = 0;
    public String msje = "";
    private String res = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        usuario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usuario);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        ingresar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ingresar);

        ingresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String username = usuario.getText().toString();
                String pass = password.getText().toString();
                new Webserv().execute();//Los nombres de clase inician con Mayusculas
            } //fin del click view
        });
    }

    //Si no se van a usar los demas argumentos, no se definen con Void
    class Webserv extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        public String NAMESPACE = "http://ONControl_MobileWS/"; // esto puede ser una constante global 
        public String METHOD_NAME = "Login"; // esto puede ser una constante global 
        public String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ONControl_MobileWS/Login"; // esto puede ser una constante global 
        public String SOAP_ADDRESS;
        private SoapObject request;
        private HttpTransportSE transporte;
        private SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void ...voids) {
            return login();// nombres de metodos inician con minuscula
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Principal.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Iniciando sesion ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setMax(10);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //utiliza el patron de diseño de AsyncTask, la respuesta viene en la variable result
            // mostramos la respuesta en un toast
            Toast.makeText(Principal.this.getBaseContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (result.equals("Gracias por Iniciar Sesion")) {
                Principal.this.usuario.getText().toString();
                Principal.this.usuario.setText("");
                Principal.this.password.setText("");
                //envia al otro activity
                Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.menu");
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            //El llamado a un Toast (o era solo a Dialogs?) después de un finish() puede provocar un error "Activity has leaked window that was originally added"
            Toast.makeText(Principal.this, "Tarea finalizada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        //Para hacerlo de forma correcta el método login debe retornar por si mismo el response en un String
        public String login() {
            SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9020/ONControl_MobileWS.asmx";// esto puede ser una constante global e incluso ser un parametro de entrada del AsyncTask
            request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
            envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            transporte = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
            request.addProperty("usuario", usuario.getText().toString());
            request.addProperty("password", password.getText().toString());

            try {
                transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                SoapPrimitive resultado_xml = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
                return resultado_xml.toString(); //se retorna el resultado aprovechando la definicion del AsyncTask
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                return e.getMessage(); // se puede desplegar un mensaje mas definido
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Solo he modificado a mano alzada tu código, no lo he pasado por compilador alguno. Notarás que variables como `res` y `msje` ya no son necesarias.